# Make button is disabled if space is typed in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm making a system with JS with a form so that unless the user types something on a textbox, the submit button is enabled, else it will be disabled, but here's the problem: When the user types a space, the button became enabled. How can I make so the button isn't enabled unless the user types a letter? Here's the code I'm using:

```js
function enable() {
  if (document.getElementById("textsend").value === "") {
    document.getElementById('main-submit-post').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('main-submit-post').style.filter = "brightness(50%)";
    document.getElementById('main-submit-post').style.cursor = "auto";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('main-submit-post').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('main-submit-post').style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
    document.getElementById('main-submit-post').style.cursor = "pointer";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea name="content" id="textsend" onkeyup="enable()" placeholder="You can type here..."></textarea>
<hr>
<button type="submit" id="main-submit-post" disabled>Share</button>
```

As you can see, if you type just space, the button gets enabled. How can I make so it only gets enabled if the user types at the beginning a letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ^ character anchors the regular expression to the start of the string.

The \s Matches a single character other than white space. Equivalent to [^ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]. For example, /\S\w*/ matches "foo" in "foo bar".

The \d Matches any digit (Arabic numeral). Equivalent to [0-9]. For example, /\d/ or /[0-9]/ matches "2" in "B2 is the suite number".

```js
function enable() {
  const mainSubmitPost =document.getElementById('main-submit-post');
  const textSend = document.getElementById("textsend");
  
  if (textSend.value === "" || textSend.value.match(/^\d/) || textSend.value.match(/^\s/) ) {
    mainSubmitPost.disabled = true;
    mainSubmitPost.style.filter = "brightness(50%)";
    mainSubmitPost.style.cursor = "auto";
  } else {
    mainSubmitPost.disabled = false;
    mainSubmitPost.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
    mainSubmitPost.style.cursor = "pointer";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea name="content" id="textsend" onkeyup="enable()" placeholder="You can type here..."></textarea>
<hr>
<button type="submit" id="main-submit-post" disabled>Share</button>
```

Comment: When I press space, the button is still being enabled...